# Choosing between various underlying implementations of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x

Assume there already exist a few different python implementations of some abstraction. For definiteness, let's say we have various classes representing quaternions, with roughly the same standard functionality (methods, variables).

In my project, I would like the user to be able to choose the particular low-level implementation of this abstraction. At the same time, I want most of my code to be implemented in a way independent of particular low-level realization.

I guess, one solution would be to create my own class (instantiated with a parameter selecting the particular implementation), within which the choice will be done.

Smth like this:

```
class ExistingQuat1(...): 
    ...

class ExistingQuat2(...):
    ...

class MyQuat( self, ..., implementation : str = None )
    ...
    _low_level_q : Union[ ExistingQuat1, ExistingQuat2 ]
    def __init__():
        if implementation == 'ExistingQuat1':
            self._low_level_q = ExistingQuat1(...) 
        if implementation == 'ExistingQuat2':
            self._low_level_q = ExistingQuat2(...) 
    
    def __add__( self, other ):
        return self.low_level_q + other.low_level_q

# Somewhere else in my code:
q1 = MyQuat()
q2 = MyQuat()
q3 = q1 + q2  # Uses the appropriate method
```

I can also imagine a slightly fancier but potentially riskier approach:

```
class MyQuat( self, ..., implementation_class : Union[ ExistingQuat1, ExistingQuat2 ] )
    ...
    _low_level_q : Union[ ExistingQuat1, ExistingQuat2 ]
    def __init__():
        self. = implementation_class(...)
    
    def __add__( self, other ):
        return self.low_level_q + other.low_level_q
```

What would be the correct way of achieving what I want?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIU, **[Factory method pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern)** has the same purpose. Snippet from the reference:

```
class GreekLocalizer:
    """A simple localizer a la gettext"""

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.translations = {"dog": "σκύλος", "cat": "γάτα"}

    def localize(self, msg: str) -> str:
        """We'll punt if we don't have a translation"""
        return self.translations.get(msg, msg)


class EnglishLocalizer:
    """Simply echoes the message"""

    def localize(self, msg: str) -> str:
        return msg


def get_localizer(language: str = "English") -> object:

    """Factory"""
    localizers = {
        "English": EnglishLocalizer,
        "Greek": GreekLocalizer,
    }

    return localizers[language]()
```

**References:**

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/patterns/creational/factory.py